# How to scrape nested divs with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from a website. First I authenticate and start the session. There is no problem in this part. But I would like to scrape my test questions. So there are 100 Questions in a test with a unique url, but only members can have access to.

```
with requests.session() as s:

s.post(loginURL, data=payLoad)
res = s.get(targetURL)

res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems = soup.find_all("div", class_="Question-Container")
print(elems)
```

After I try to run this code, I didn't receive the data which I wanted.
The output looks likes this

```
[<div class="Questionboard-body Question-Container">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="text-right">
<span><b>Question Id: </b></span><span class="DisplayQNr"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="QuestionText">
<div class="qText"></div>
</div>
<div class="QuestionOptions" hideanswer="false"></div>
<div class="QuestionSolution" hideanswer="false">
<button class="showSolutionBtn btn btn-primary-alt">Show Solution</button>
<div class="QuestionCorrectOptions text-center"></div>
<div class="DetailedSolution text-center"></div>
</div>
</div>]
```

Output which I want is the data inside those elements.
The div trees looks like this. There are alot of divs, where class="DisplayQNr" is for questionID, there is one more div QuestionText but the question Text is inside class="qText". There are four options for each question, class=QuestionOptions and so on. I want to scrape all of them. Image attach for better clarity.
[Screenshot of nested divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fhF8.png)

Comment: Assuming content of container is generated dynamically e.g. by JavaScript. May check selenium that would render the page like a browser will do or look for xhr requests the content may called from.

Comment: @HedgeHog The page is static and I got the entire html of page using requests. `res = requests.get(url) print(res)` gives the entire html page. With all the required divs etc. But I want to extract only the question part ie div of class Questionboard-body Question-Container.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in elems:
    gg = i.find_all('div')
print(gg)
```

Comment: Not working. I'm getting the same div tables, but this time `<div class="Questionboard-body Question-Container">` isn't in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as you mentioned in the comments, all data / content is in your `soup` you could go with:

```
...
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
data = []
for e in soup.select('.Question-Container'):
    d = {
        'question': e.select_one('.qText').text if e.select_one('.qText') else None
    }
    d.update(dict(s.stripped_strings for s in e.select('.answerText')))

    data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output would be something like that:

|  | question | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | my question text | answer text a | answer text b |

...